# Observed instances of massive gas inflow and AGN restart due to cluster-cluster merger?

Tags: galaxy, radio-astronomy, galaxy-cluster, active-galaxy

Works such as [Acreman et al. (2003)](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-lookup/doi/10.1046/j.1365-8711.2003.06504.x) have demonstrated via simulations the possibility of gas being stripped off a galaxy due to interaction with a galaxy cluster.

Have there been confirmed instances where a cluster-cluster merger led to the infall of huge amounts of gas onto one of the clusters? Further, have there been instances of cluster-cluster merger leading to restarting Active Galactic Nuclei (AGN) activity?

Comment: Surely if you strip gas out of galaxies, you stop AGN activity?

Comment: The galaxy from which gas has been stripped, yes. But does the stripped off gas deposit onto the interacting cluster leading to refueling of a quiescent AGN in this cluster?